# How do I identify suitable ICs (for JTAG multiplexing)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, jtag

I'm quite a rookie in the hardware-electronic field so please bear with me. I want to create a multiplexer for JTAG with 1:16, so one input and up to sixteen outputs. Actually I only want to flash the MCU so I don't need specific JTAG possibilities. On [this post at TI](https://e2e.ti.com/support/switches-multiplexers-group/switches-multiplexers/f/switches-multiplexers-forum/1095181/faq-what-analog-switch-multiplexer-should-i-use-for-jtag-applications) are some ICs provided which seem to fit but for once I need ICs with more outputs(?) plus I would like to know in general how to choose or rather how to find a suitable IC in general.

In this specific case, the requirements are:

1. 4 Pin Protocol (5th pin optional) – TCK (Test Clock), TMS (Test Mode Select), TDI (Test Data In), TDO (Test Data Out), TRST (Test Reset – Optional)
2. Voltage Levels: 1.8V-5V
3. Frequency: 10MHz-100MHz

Does one need to scroll through endless vendor lists or is there a smarter way to go?

Comment: are you aware that the very idea of JTAG is that you don't *need* a multiplexer?

Comment: Is this a multi-up fixture or a single PCBA? Which MCU? What is the maximum length of the boundary scan chain?

Comment: Re @MarcusMüller: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382372/how-to-connect-multiple-jtag-devices/382377#382377 for an example.

Comment: Do you need boundary scan? Or are you wanting to just program the MCU memory on several devices?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. If you daisy chain your JTAG connections, you can have lots of devices with one JTAG connection (I think there's a limit to the lenght of JTAG chain, but can't remember the details of that).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I "need" a multiplexer because I don't want to change the software anytime I change something in the chain.

Comment: @LiorBilia I'm afraid I can't answer your questions. The MCU will be e.h. a stm32. I don't need the boundary scan, I use JTAG only to flash the MCU.

Comment: @RussellH Yes, I only want to load firmware onto several devices.

Comment: @Puffafish I want to flash multiple devices via JTAG with the help of a multiplexer. As I will change MCUs frequently I don't want to set up a daisy chain as I will use three different MCUs but in total up to 16 MCUs, so the chip itself varies and the amount of each type.

Comment: @Ben thanks for clearing that up! (I don't fully understand it, but I don't trust your assessment on that you need a multiplexer). That brings me to pointing out that the ti article too linked to does indeed, in the first bullet point list, explain which requirements of JTAG are important (4 signals, voltage range, speed), and that they simply chose devices from their product table that fulfill these! That's actually the same price as I would have recommended in an answer :)

Comment: Re: not enough ports: you might need to build a tree of multiplexers then. Like for example one 4-multiplexer, feeding four 4-multiplexers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What else would or could I use instead of a multiplexer? Relating to the TI article I wonder why, e.g., they didn't suggest 74HC138 or 74HC151? Indeed, I would need a small tree of MUX, I'm thinking about a 1:2 to route to two 1:8? So in total 3 MUX then.

Comment: I don't have the datasheets of these two chips at hand, but maybe they are just too slow, or not voltage-tolerant enough, or inferioir to the chips they did present in some other way (power consumption). Or, maybe, they just could not be moved to make a whole-market overview and picked a couple of examples, with sales intent. Again, the principle they demonstrate in the article is what I would go with: write down the requirements of your signal (for JTAG, they even did that for you in the article). Then, go to an electronics distributor website, click to the multiplexers and filter by these.

Comment: There are off the shelf gang programmers, if that's what you need.
https://www.st.com/en/partner-products-and-services/production-flash-programmer.html#product-details