Simplest way to design a PCB to mass program 10 ESP32's over a single high-speed USB-C port

I am trying to flash up to 10 ESP32's with firmware over USB (similar to the ESP32 Programming Tool that has a USB to UART converter), but I am trying to do it from a single high-speed USB-C line, and I am not sure what the best way to go about doing this will be.
I noticed that USB-UART IC's allow for a single COM port, so I was thinking of hooking up 10 of these CP2102's, but I am not sure if I can just connect all of them up the same D+/D- the main USB-C input, and just have my PC enumerate all 10 COM ports and avoid collisions while trying to flash all 10 at once.
Would I need to basically integrate a USB HUB IC into this PCB and then fanout the USB HUB outputs into each USB-UART IC? I see there are some IC's like this that allow for 4x UART COM ports per USB input, so perhaps I would just need to make a hub that has 3 USB outputs and then wire each USB output into each USB to Quad UART IC's?
I was trying to find something off the shelf to do this, but I couldn't find anything that does what I am trying to do for mass flashing of ESP32's.

"I am not sure if I can just connect all of them up the same D+/D-" - no, you definitely can't do that. USB connects a single DFP to a single UFP. You'll need to use hubs.

Eh, sorry to say I do not know the specifics of ESP32.  However, If you can program/flash via JTAG, then the JTAG interface certainly supports daisy-chaining - but you must design your PCB for it.  See the oldie-but-goodie: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382372/how-to-connect-multiple-jtag-devices

this makes no sense ... you can load 10 ESP32's over 10 USB ports

It depends on the details which you do not share. You might have an X-Y problem. Maybe the quickest way is to buy the ESPs preprogrammed. By the time you connect 10 boards to your programmer, the first ESPs could have been already programmed if you do them 10 at one go. However, we can only assist you with making a 10 port USB serial device since that is what you asked.

You cannot connect more than one chip to USB. So you cannot put 10 CP2102 pins in parallel to one USB port.
You need a hub. Or rather, multiple hub ICs as likely you cannot find a 10-port USB hub IC.
Your second solution is better. You only need one hub IC and connect three quad UART ICs for 12 serial ports. The enumeration will be a pain and nothin can guaranee you get COM1 through COM12, or if there are gaps due to existing ports, or even the order of which of the chips is ready first to get the first 4 allocated.
What you could do is to put 1 or 2 MCUs with enough serial ports and USB connnection to PC. A single MCU could provide easily 5 USB serial ports, and even multiplex 5 ports into 10 connectors.
Or just 1 or 2 MCUs that has enough serial ports and does not require a PC for programming the ESPs, it could take the firmware from SD card or USB stick and work without a PC to program ESPs.
So you can already do a mock-up by buying a hub or two, some USB uarts (single, dual, quad) and put them in a black box instead of desiging it by yourself. Then you will see the problems before you decide to design and build all that on single PCB.
You could even throw in a SBC like a Raspberry Pi so you don't even need the PC for programming.
Gang programmers do exist but rarely you would gang-program MCUs via slow UART on your own. The JTAG should be far better, as mentioned, it can be chained and it is anyway faster than UART programming, especially if you can't use USB natively to ESPs.
